# Cant read file name with Russian char from FileInputstream

Tags: android, unicode, fileinputstream

I read some files from phone storage (which are in Russian name) i listed all files it will give me all file path correct but the time when i try to read from `new FileInputStream(file)` it gave me file not found exception i don't know why.
my code is like the following :

```
FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(file); //this line gave error and file path is /storage/emulated/0/bhanuдосвидания.txt
```

and logcat is the following :

```
02-10 15:48:58.000: W/System.err(16013): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/bhanuдосвидания.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 02-10 15:48:58.020: W/System.err(16013): at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409) 02-10 15:48:58.050: W/System.err(16013): at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78) 02-10 15:48:58.050: W/System.err(16013): at com.S3Upload.UploadActivity$allCalculation.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:16‌​71) 02-10 15:48:58.080: W/System.err(16013):
```

please help me...

Comment: please post your code

Comment: FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(file); this line gave error and file path is /storage/emulated/0/bhanuдосвидания.txt

Comment: did you try `FileInputStream("file", "encoding");` and use encode like `UTF-8` or `UTF-16`

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan there is no any option in FileInputStream which u give dude :)

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: sorry for my mistake, yes you right, i thought that you need `Reader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file"), "UTF-8"));`

Comment: dude in this line you use FileInputStream("file") and this will give error dude i already try this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the problem is like you change your file name to lower case. Try to remove lower case from your code and check.

Answer (score 0):

please try to do something like the following :

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(
                      new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```

Comment: dude in this line you use FileInputStream("file") and this will give error dude i already try this :)

Comment: 02-10 15:48:58.000: W/System.err(16013): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/bhanuдосвидания.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-10 15:48:58.020: W/System.err(16013):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-10 15:48:58.050: W/System.err(16013):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
02-10 15:48:58.050: W/System.err(16013):  at com.S3Upload.UploadActivity$allCalculation.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:1671)
02-10 15:48:58.080: W/System.err(16013):

Comment: dude   new FileInputStream(file) is always give error just try in your PC u found it with Russian file name

Comment: please post your file path in the android SD card

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/bhanuдосвидания.txt

Comment: please update your question with the fill source code , including the path , the file object and your FileInputStream

Comment: there is nothing in whole code dude the prob is in this line only just do in your pc itself u found same error with russian file

Comment: thats why i am asking you to post your code to see where is the problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47161/discussion-between-bhanu-sharma-and-amrola)